# Vue Same class divs, expand only the child, without (this) parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

All children and parents `div` are with the same class. I'd attached `v-on:click`method to toggled only the child one of the clicked parent, not all children. If I add (this) the method doesn't work. Thank you.

```
        <div class="expand-box" v-on:click="textToggle()">
            <div class="expand-title">Lorem ipsum</div>
            <div class="expand-text">Child</div>
        </div>
        <div class="expand-box" v-on:click="textToggle()">
            <div class="expand-title">Lorem Ipsum</div>
            <span class="expand-text">Child.</span>
        </div>



mounted(){
      this.hideText();
},

methods: {
      hideText: function() {
        $(".expand-text").hide();
      },
      textToggle: function() {
        $(".expand-text").toggle(300);
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

First when you are using `v-on:click` you need set function name like `v-on:click="textToggle"` if you are not passing parameters.

It's not recommanded to use jQuery alond side Vuejs for animation and dom manipulation,
you need to use css or Vuejs animation :

- CSS ANIMATION :

  - https://codepen.io/khofaai/pen/qJXbbr
  - http://optimizely.github.io/vuejs.org/guide/transitions.html

```css
.msg {
    transition: all .3s ease;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #eee;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.msg.v-enter, .msg.v-leave {
    height: 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<p class="msg" v-if="show" v-transition>Hello!</p>
```

Comment: yes you have reason the use of Jquery inside Vue.js will mess the code and generates some issues

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `$event` as a parameter of `textToggle` so that it becomes `v-on:click="textToggle($event)"` then your method will use this reference to toggle that element using,

```
textToggle: function(elem) {
  $(elem.target).toggle(300);
}
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  },
  mounted() {
    this.hideText();
  },

  methods: {
    hideText: function() {
      $(".expand-text").hide();
    },
    textToggle: function(elem) {
      $(elem.target).toggle(300);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<div id='app'>
  <div class="expand-box" v-on:click="textToggle($event)">
    <div class="expand-title">Lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class="expand-text">Child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="expand-box" v-on:click="textToggle($event)">
    <div class="expand-title">Lorem Ipsum</div>
    <span class="expand-text">Child.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also use `ref` in your HTML element to get the reference of that element like:

**HTML**

```
<div class="expand-box" v-on:click="textToggle('el1')" ref="el1">
    <div class="expand-title">Lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class="expand-text">Child</div>
</div>
<div class="expand-box" v-on:click="textToggle('el2')" ref="el2">
    <div class="expand-title">Lorem Ipsum</div>
    <span class="expand-text">Child.</span>
</div>
```

**METHOD**

```
textToggle: function(refId) {
  this.$refs[refId].toggle(300);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. With ref it returns "Questions.vue?abee:44 Uncaught TypeError: this.$refs[refId].toggle is not a function"

Comment: Now the parent element is toggled (hidden on click)